# Is 2nd hand smoking worse than 1st hand smoking

Tags: smoking, second-hand-smoke

I have heard many things about smoking and a main issue as of one being that 2nd hand smoking is worse than 1st hand smoking itself? **(I do not smoke I am just around someone who does smoke)**

Is this rumor true? If *so* why is this, and what should I do if I can smell it or if I am around them when they light the cigarette?

Comment: Hi fbleb, welcome! Part of SE is providing the source of your information, including what you've found when trying to answer your own question. For future questions, consider that someone answering may want to see where you got that information/rumor.  So if you google it and show in your post, that would improve the quality of your question and the potential answer you will get. For future reference, as @Narusan already nailed this answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

Yes, if one was to inhale the same amount of smoke passively as smokers inhale actively, it would be more dangerous. This is hardly the case though, as smokers also inhale parts of second hand smoke, and because as always, *dosis facit venenum*.

---

### Risk of Second Hand Smoke

**Risk of developing cancer**

> Exposure to secondhand smoke raises the risk -- **by as much as 30 percent [1.3 times]** -- that others will get lung cancer and many other types of cancer, it can lead to emphysema, and it is bad for your heart.
>
> *Source: [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/smoking-cessation/effects-of-secondhand-smoke), Emphasis Mine, Annotation Mine*

The lower risk of developing cancer is because passive smokers don't inhale the same amount of smoke - you usually walk past a smoker and not stand right next to them until they have finished their cigarette.

**Inhalation of toxic fumes**

> There are 2 types of tobacco smoke:
>
> 1. Mainstream smoke, which is directly inhaled through the mouth end of the cigarette
> 2. Sidestream smoke, which comes from the burning tip of the cigarette
>
> Second-hand smoke is made up of sidestream smoke and
>   exhaled mainstream smoke, mixed with the surrounding air.
>
> Sidestream smoke is about **4 times more toxic than mainstream smoke,
>   although people inhale it in a more diluted form**. This is because
>   sidestream smoke contains much higher levels of many of the poisons
>   and cancer-causing chemicals in cigarettes, including:
>
> - At least 3 times as much carbon monoxide
> - 10-30 times more nitrosamines
> - Between 15–300 times more ammonia
>
> *Source: [cancerresearchuk.org](http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/about-cancer/causes-of-cancer/smoking-and-cancer/passive-smoking)*

However, the total amount of toxic fumes passive smokers inhale is less than what smokers inhale, because the former are not exposed to smoke as often as the latter.

**Risk of Developing Heart Diseases or Strokes**

> Breathing secondhand smoke can cause coronary heart disease, including
>   heart attack and stroke. Know the facts:
>
> - Secondhand smoke causes nearly 34,000 early deaths from coronary    heart disease each year in the United States among 
>     nonsmokers.
> - Nonsmokers who **breathe secondhand smoke at home or at work increase
>
>     their risk of developing heart disease by 25–30%.**
> - Breathing secondhand smoke interferes with the normal functioning of    the heart, blood, and vascular systems in ways that increase
>     your    risk of having a heart attack.
> - Even briefly breathing secondhand smoke can damage the lining of    blood vessels and cause your blood to become stickier. These changes
>     can cause a deadly heart attack.
>
> *Source: [cdc.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/tobacco/campaign/tips/diseases/heart-disease-stroke.html)*

Again, the risk is lower than the risk of smokers because it is *only* an exposure during work or at home and are not expected to inhale the same amount of smoke as bystanders as smokers do.

### Risks of First Hand Smoke

**Risk of developing cancer**

> People who smoke cigarettes are **15 to 30 times more likely** to get lung cancer or die from lung cancer than people who do not smoke. Even smoking a few cigarettes a day or smoking occasionally increases the risk of lung cancer. The more years a person smokes and the more cigarettes smoked each day, the more risk goes up.
>
> *Source: [cdc.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/cancer/lung/basic_info/risk_factors.htm), Emphasis Mine*

**Toxic fumes**

> Cigarette smoke is a mixture of over 4000 chemicals, many of which are
>   harmful to the human body. All currently available tobacco products
>   that are smoked deliver substantial amounts of toxic chemicals to
>   their users and those who breathe their smoke.
>
> Of the more than 4000 chemicals present in cigarette smoke, more than
>   60 have been identified as cancer causing chemicals, 11 of which are
>   known to cause cancer in humans and 8 that probably cause cancer in
>   humans.
>
> With approximately **one non-smoker dying due to secondhand smoke
>   exposure for every eight smokers dying** of smoking-related disease it
>   is no surprise that secondhand smoke has been designated a known human
>   carcinogen (cancer-causing agent). Further, **about half of regular
>   smokers will die of a smoking-related disease** and have a **reduced life
>   expectancy of about 13 to 16 years** as compared with non- smokers.
>
> *Source: [Australian Department for Health](http://www.health.gov.au/internet/quitnow/publishing.nsf/Content/1F9BA81210676CF8CA257A0D001F122C/$File/toxic.pdf), Emphasis Mine*

**Risk of Heart Diseases and Strokes**

> If you smoke, your chance of dying from a heart attack is **2 to 3 times
>   greater** than that of a person who does not smoke. About **1 out of 4
>   heart attacks is believed to be directly related to smoking**. Smoking
>   is a much more important risk factor for a heart attack than high
>   cholesterol, obesity, high blood pressure, or stress.
>   A person who smokes is twice as likely to die from a stroke as a person who does not smoke.
>
> *Source: [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/smoking-cessation/tc/smoking-heart-attack-and-stroke-risks-topic-overview), Emphasis Mine*

---

### If you have children

Second hand smoking is especially damaging to children:

> Every day millions of children in the UK are exposed to secondhand
>   smoke, which puts them at **increased risk of lung disease, meningitis
>   and cot death**. Treatment, hospital and GP visits for secondhand smoke
>   related illnesses cost the NHS more than £23.6 million each year.
>
> *Source: [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/childrens-health-up-in-smoke), Emphasis Mine*

Early exposure to chemicals is a lot more damaging than during adulthood.

> Passive smoking causes lasting damage to children's arteries,
>   prematurely ageing their blood vessels by more than three years, say
>   researchers.
>
> *Source: [BBC.com](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-26432111)*

This can lead to early heard attacks and other coronary diseases.

> Exposure of unborn children to tobacco smoke may also increase the
>   risk of miscarriage, low birth weight and sudden infant death syndrome
>   (SIDS), or ‘cot death’. There is strong evidence that the babies of
>   mothers who smoke after birth have more lung diseases in their first
>   year of life and have double the normal risk of serious airway
>   infections.
>
> *Source: [Gov.au](https://www.health.gov.au/internet/main/publishing.nsf/Content/2C2DEB2D69E29B0DCA257BF0001E7410/$File/tobpass.pdf)*

If you have kids, you definitely should follow the advice below.

### What you can do

> You can protect yourself and your family from secondhand smoke by:
>
> - Quitting smoking if you are not already a nonsmoker
> - Not allowing anyone to smoke anywhere in or near your home
> - Not allowing anyone to smoke in your car, even with the windows down
> - Making sure your children’s day care center and schools are tobacco-free
> - Seeking out restaurants and other places that do not allow smoking (if your state still allows smoking in public areas)
> - Teaching your children to stay away from secondhand smoke.
> - Being a good role model by not smoking or using any other type of  tobacco.
>
> *Source: [cdc.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/tobacco/data_statistics/fact_sheets/secondhand_smoke/general_facts/index.htm)*

Comment: I'll include a section about risks of heart attacks and strokes as soon as I find meaningful data.

Comment: Thank you for the rock solid answer. In conclusion 2nd hand smoking is worse due to the fact that there is more chemicals being inhaled from the tip of the cigarette, than the person who is actually smoking the cigarette.

Comment: @fbleb Exactly. However, smokers have higher risks of cancer etc. because the total amount of smoke and chemicals they are exposed to is higher (they inhale smoke more often than bystanders)

Comment: If second smoking means inhaling the smoke from the tip of the cigarette, then a smoker is both a first-hand and a second-hand smoker. How is then mere second-hand smoking more dangerous?

Comment: The answer provides the evidence that second-hand smoking is harmful, but no evidence that it is more harmful than first-hand smoking. You are actually suggesting this in your opening. Even if one inhales the same amount of smoke as an active smoker, it's not the same smoke and no evidence that is more dangerous. I'm not trying to manipulate any definitions here, but if something is dangerous, it needs to be practically dangerous (a higher percent of diseases in passive than in active smokers), not just somehow theoretically more dangerous.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma How could smokers not inhale SHS? They breath the same air the person standing next to them breaths.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Smokers breathe the ambient air that they just blew clouds of smoke into, and they have a burning cigarette smoldering away in their immediate proximity every second its lit. I'm quite confident that smokers are exposed to far more SHS than non-smokers.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Your own wording: "second hand smoking is more dangerous than first hand smoking, but only if you inhale the same amount of smoke, _which you don't._" Your words. You said it here and you said it in your article opening: second-hand smoking is not more dangerous than first-hand smoking, because you don't inhale nearly the same amount of smoke as the active smoker.

Comment: An active smoker smokes a cigarette for 5 minutes, inhaling first-hand and his/her own second-hand smoke. A passive smoker stands nearby inhaling only the second-hand smoke for the same 5 minutes. This is comparable. Second-hand _smokE_ supossedly being 4 times more toxic than first-hand smoke does not automatically make second-hand _smokING_ (time, amount...) more harmful.

Comment: @Jan, at CareyGregory: Of course, you‘re both right. I have corrected the post now, I really don’t know why I haven’t acted on your comments before...

Comment: LOL... what's four years give or take?